# Getting error when importing package:intl/intl.dart'

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety, pubspec

Getting an warning when trying to `import 'package:intl/intl.dart';`
but has warning

> Warning: The library 'package:intl/intl.dart' is legacy, and shouldn't be imported into a null safe library.

I am importing this to implement `DateFormat`,

if there is any other possible solution that is also welcome.

Comment: Your `pubspec.yaml` likely is specifying an old version of `intl` that pre-dates null-safety.  Fix it to require a newer a version.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade all your pubspec `dependencies` into null-safety.

Run `dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety`

and then run `dart pub upgrade --null-safety`